# Error when dowloading data using tensorflow_datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use fashion_mnist for a GAN and when I load the data I get this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 2
      1 builder = tfds.builder('fashion_mnist', data_dir=folder_path)
----> 2 builder.download_and_prepare()
      3 ds = builder.as_dataset(split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)

File e:\Info\Anaconda\envs\ia\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\logging\__init__.py:169, in _FunctionDecorator.__call__(self, function, instance, args, kwargs)
    167 metadata = self._start_call()
    168 try:
--> 169   return function(*args, **kwargs)
    170 except Exception:
    171   metadata.mark_error()

File e:\Info\Anaconda\envs\ia\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\dataset_builder.py:646, in DatasetBuilder.download_and_prepare(self, download_dir, download_config, file_format)
    644   self.info.read_from_directory(self._data_dir)
    645 else:
--> 646   self._download_and_prepare(
    647       dl_manager=dl_manager,
    648       download_config=download_config,
    649   )
    651   # NOTE: If modifying the lines below to put additional information in
    652   # DatasetInfo, you'll likely also want to update
    653   # DatasetInfo.read_from_directory to possibly restore these attributes
    654   # when reading from package data.
...

TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. tensorflow.python._pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(arg0: str, arg1: int)
```

I tried to load the data like here:

```
builder = tfds.builder('fashion_mnist', data_dir=folder_path)
builder.download_and_prepare()
ds = builder.as_dataset(split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)
```

and also like in this repo [FashionGan](https://github.com/nicknochnack/GANBasics/blob/main/FashionGAN-Tutorial.ipynb)

But I get the same error. I have tensorFlow version: 2.3.0 and tensorFlowDataset version: 4.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
# Load the Fashion MNIST dataset
fmnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist 

# Load the training and test split of the Fashion MNIST dataset
(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fmnist.load_data()
```